# how to pass the encoded string to url in php?

Tags: url, urlencode, url-encoding

I want to encode the url address.In my php file(test.php) I get the script name and encode it . when I echo $ss1 I got this `/sample/example/test.php` then I encode the string I got this `L3NhbXBsZS9leGFtcGxlL3Rlc3QucGhw`,Now I want to pass this in my test.php file.

```
    $ss1 = ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        echo $ss1;
$ss2=base64_encode($ss1);
echo $ss2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to pass this in my test.php file"?

Comment: I want to pass the encoded string to url address when browse the test.php file